# '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'bool' - Flutter MethodChannel

Tags: android, kotlin, dart, flutter

Getting this strange error. Seems like the MethodChannel is converting to an int instead of a bool?

```
06-07 00:16:26.589  3678  4993 E flutter : [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
06-07 00:16:26.589  3678  4993 E flutter : type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'bool' where
06-07 00:16:26.589  3678  4993 E flutter :   _Smi is from dart:core
06-07 00:16:26.589  3678  4993 E flutter :   bool is from dart:core
06-07 00:16:26.589  3678  4993 E flutter :
06-07 00:16:26.589  3678  4993 E flutter : #0  ...
```

Relevant code:

```
//the line in question
bool permission = await platform.invokeMethod("askStoragePermission"); 

//the following is the native kotlin that is called.
//The device previously had received permission so it should be going to 
//the 'else' section (and no permission request dialogue appeared)
"askStoragePermission" -> {
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 35)
    currentResult = result
  } else {
    result.success(true)
  }
}
```

No idea what could be causing this. It seems to be working in debug mode in the emulator (this error is release apk on a real device).

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Never would have tried it...

Comment: It's a known issue and required quite often, especially for release builds but also for debug builds when you think that changes in your code don't take effect in the app.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is there any explanation for this issue? any issue filed on github over it?

Answer (score 1):

Running `flutter clean` seems to have fixed this. Make sure to do it before every release build, I guess!

Comment: Did you find any explanation for it. I am facing this issue in 2021!